# How can I send unicode characters by using tmux command?

Tags: unicode, tmux, non-ascii-characters

Here is my tmux command

```
tmux send-key -t session:window.pane say 安安 enter
```

but the result is

```
root@debian:~# say
```

(There is no "安安", unicode characters.)

**How can I send the non-ASCII Characters???**

(my tmux version is 1.8)

Comment: hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in tmux 1.8 and earlier. It is fixed in the SVN version of tmux. See this thread for more information: https://www.mail-archive.com/tmux-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg04478.html

Comment: thank you. I've installed git master version 1.9. Now, it works. XD~